# TSQL equivalent of PostgreSQL "PERFORM" keyword?

Tags: c#, t-sql, postgresql, performance-testing, multiple-resultsets

I'm testing query performance in a loop.  Rather than return a hundred duplicates of a result set, I want to run a select statement hundreds of times, discarding the results each time.

PostgreSQL has the syntax "perform select...", which will execute the select statement and discard the results. "37.6.2. Executing a Query With No Result" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html

Is there an equivalent keyword in TSQL?

I'm aware that SSMS has a "Discard results" options, but it appears that the results are not discarded after each iteration and would still accumulate in memory until all iterations are complete.  I suppose selecting into a temporary variable could work, but it would be much simpler to just discard the results with a keyword.  I'd rather avoid construction of  table variable definitions and the potential overhead of storing the results in temporary tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through the SQL-92 specification for an equivalent keyword, but I was unable to find any and, in my experiences, don't know of one specific to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.Net, execute the query without a result set by using command.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sqlConnectString = "Data Source=(local);Integrated security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;";

        string sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id = 2";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete, connection);
        connection.Open( );
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery( );
        Console.WriteLine("{0} row(s) affected.", rowsAffected);
        Console.WriteLine("Record with Id = 2 deleted.");
        connection.Close( );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running it in TSQL, not ADO.Net.  The issue isn't a matter of ignoring the result set, which is all ExecuteNonQuery accomplishes as far as I know.  The issue is to ENSURE that SQL Server discards the result set as soon as each SELECT statement finishes, when thousands of select statements are issued in a loop in a single TSQL batch, so it can effectively test performance of the statement without wasting resources which could interfere with the test.